# How to share my eth-wired internet from my pc to my eth-wired raspberry pi, non-wifi

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, dhcp, ethernet

I have a PC and RPI, both running debian.

My PC has internet access via ethernet(not wifi), and I connect to my RPI with ssh via another ethernet from the PC to the RPI.

The PC to RPI connection uses static ip setup in */etc/network/interfaces*

However, I am unable to get to the internet on my raspberry pi

How can I let my rpi share the internet through my pc?

I have ensured *cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward* displays **1**

tried updating iptables

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Ive also tried many other iptables commands and about 5 hours of trial and error, but nothing seems to work, i have removed any failed iptables updates from the iptables database to avoid problems.

My PC */etc/network/interfaces*

```
#ethernet internet into pc
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
  request_prefix 1

#eth1 = eth-usb adapter to connect to rpi
auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
  iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.101/24
```

My RPI */etc/network/interfaces*

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.100/24
  dns-nameservers 192.168.0.101
```

Networking output for troubleshooting.

PC cmd *ip r*

```
default via 192.168.6.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1000
[IP MASKED] via 192.168.6.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.101
192.168.6.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.6.169 metric 100
192.168.6.1 dev eth0 proto static scope link metric 100
```

RPI cmd *ip r*

```
default via 192.168.0.101 dev eth0 online
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.100
```

cmd *ip rule* on PC and RPI both output

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

on PC cmd *sudo iptables-save -c*

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [342:36803]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [168:27052]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [70:6256]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [66:5191]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb  4 13:58:41 2024
```

PC Cmd *sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v*

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 255 packets, 38565 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: @A.B the "D"efault was because I couldnt copy/paste in SSH putty, I had to manually type it out. I will run those commands you requested now and update my post

Also, what should I set gateway ip address to, as you said its needed?

Comment: @A.B nft list ruleset - debian reports *nft: command not found*

Comment: Ive spent over 10 hours going around in circles, willing to pay £100 BTC if somebody can get it working.

Also,you said gateway is mandatory in the pi, what ip should I put?

Comment: @A.B added results of iptables-save -c into post

Comment: The result doesn't include your MASQUERADE rule you wrote in the question. Can you explain why?

Comment: You should rewrite your question with accurate information: revalidate everything you already did, step by step, and then correct accordingly what's written in the question. I keep thinking that information provided isn't accurate.

Comment: @A.B probably because as my main post says, ive tried so many rules I had to keep erasing and adding, Im going to re-add this iptables rule, reboot the PC, reboot the PI, and see if theres any difference, which I doubt there will be.

Comment: adding the iptables back in makes the post valid

Comment: @A.B I have edited and updated the output of *iptabes-save -c*
The rpi still cannot get internet access.

Im thinking to re-image the whole pi, and delete all network interfaces on PC, and start again, but I doubt there will be much difference

Comment: Still no MASQUERADE in iptables-save -c's output: you keep shooting yourself in the foot by providing inaccurate information in the question. I don't want to spend more time on this, because I can see the inconsistency, sorry.

Comment: @A.B I ran the command I posted in my opening post.

Comment: @A.B *iptables -t nat -L -n -v* shows the POSTROUTING is present. added results in my post, perhaps the MASQUERADE is not correctly being added, but iptables didnt produce any errors... I need to run it with verbose flags if possible